# Tag for MatterControl app

Tags: discussion

As we got tags for other applications like cura | slic3r | meshmixer etc. I vote to add new tag mattercontrol for MatterControl application. There could be also synonym matter-control.

In general we could also consider synonyms for all said applications according to pattern app-applicationname so app-slic3r | app-cura and so on.

Comment: Nice idea! I have created the tags for you.

Comment: Thank you @TormodHaugene but don't you think it would be better to have matter-control as a synonym? I'm not very familiar with synonyms subject but i suppose they act like tags but don't polute tag namespace.

Comment: I do not know if we have any definite tag name conventions, but from what I understand we use a dash when there is a separation between words. For the MatterControl tag, I guess it then depends on whether the CamelCasing should be interpreted as literal space or not. I created a [question](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/151/naming-convention-for-tags-with-camelcase-or-pre-fix) regarding this, so that we can put it up for discussion.