# Naming convention for tags with CamelCase or Pre-Fix

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there any official naming conventions for tag names on Stack Exchange? And if not, how should tags be named?

From what I understand, one typically adds a *dash* (-) where you normally would leave a *space*, but how about tags that derive from words that are *[CamelCased](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/tag-for-mattercontrol-app)*, or somehow *[Prefixed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postproduction)*?

Examples (which also shows some inconsistencies):

```
Topic            | Existing tag         | Alternative tag?
----------------------------------------------------------
MatterControl    | matter-control       | mattercontrol
MakerBot         | makerbot             | maker-bot
Post-production  | postproduction       | post-production
Post-processing  | post-processing      | postprocessing
Multi-material   | multi-material       | multimaterial
```

Which of the above tag alternatives should we go for?

Comment: Makerbot and MatterControl are proper nouns. In the case of MatterControl you should use camelcase (since that's how MatterControl does it themselves) and "Makerbot" should just be "Makerbot" (no hyphens or camelcase).

Answer (score 5):

Looking at other SE sites, the most common approach seems to make everything lowercase (including names and trademarks) and using hyphens whenever there would be a space or hyphen in normal usage.

As such:

- MatterControl becomes mattercontrol
- Makerbot becomes makerbot
- Post-production becomes post-production
- Post-processing becomes post-processing
- Multi-material becomes multi-material

Comment: I agree that this seems like the most sensible way of setting tag names. If no one has any strong opinions against this, I suggest we go through the tags archive and correct what we can, and keep this in mind when reviewing new posts.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers already posted, I am changing [postproduction](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postproduction) to [post-production](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production), I have only just seen this and it immediately looked odd.

Also, <strike>what is the difference between [post-production](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production) and [post-processing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-processing), or are they synonyms? [post-production](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production) has no description whatsoever.</strike> See [What is the difference between post-production and post-processing?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-difference-between-post-production-and-post-processing)

Comment: According to this, [tag:underextrusion] and [tag:overextrusion] should also be changed accordingly.

Comment: Yes, well spotted! :-) As Tom states in [his answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/155/4762) hyphens replace spaces. Can you make the change, or is this something that only high-rep users can do? I'm not sure (not without checking). If you can't then tell me and I'll do it. You should also probably post an answer (here) stating that change is going to be made - so that there is a record of it (in an answer and not in an ephemeral comment)

Comment: I think that I can't do this yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would say we could use synonyms to stay with clear tag namespace.In this case we apply following pattern (especially for proper name (product name)):

```
Topic          | Existing tag    | Synonym?
---------------+-----------------+--------------
MatterControl  | mattercontrol   | matter-control
```

I think dash could be used to separate kinda branch for example:

```
app-cura, app-mattercontrol, app-meshmixer << these could be also synonyms
3d-printer, 3d-models, 3d-design
```

of course we already have tags like

```
feature-request, switching-power-supply
```

but they are descriptive and would be unreadable written as one word, one may say these describe actions

Comment: I agree, if someone accidentally creates a new tag for an existing similar tag, we can just create synonyms.

Comment: @tbm0115 Synonyms aren't really designed for minor variations in tense or formatting; text completion will take care of that. Synonyms were intended to be used where there are two completely *different* words used to describe a concept (think: 'car' > 'auto'). Adding a lot of unnecessary synonyms will only fill your tag listings with a lot of unnecessary entries. I would avoid it.

Comment: So in other words, we should try to avoid having *both* "matter-control" and "mattercontrol", but rather stick with only one? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @darthpixel, I'm not sure if I think having tags that prefixes what the topic is about, such as *app-* mattercontrol, is a good idea, since this strategy only would make sense to already existing users familiar with the pattern. In addition, do we really need a prefix to avoid ambiguity in the tag names?

Comment: @TormodHaugene maybe you are right. I always gravity to organize things, that's why I proposed app-. Of course it's not necessary and of course it will mean something only for existing users. So there was no such proposition ;)