# Tag required for "object removal from print bed"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

With respect to this question, [How can you both reliably print and remove your item without breaking it when detatching it?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6041/how-can-you-both-reliably-print-and-remove-your-item-without-breaking-it-when-de), the OP rightly states the following:

> ps. I didn't find (and I can't make one), for what I think would be, the correct tag(s) for this post. Please forgive me.

Does anyone have a good suggestion regarding this? Should the question be re-tagged? Is a new tag even required?

The question is currently tagged under [print-quality](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-quality) and [bed-leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-leveling). Are these sufficient? They don't really seem appropriate. Is there an already existing tag that would fit?

I thought of  `tag:object removal`, `tag:print removal` or `bed scrapping`, but they all sound a bit off (except, maybe, for *print-removal*). What is the technical term (if there is one), for those in the know, for this activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imho that could be a `post-processing` category/tag.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. There is also a `postproduction` tag, without a description. After a quick_ glance at the questions tagged `postproduction`, I can't see what the difference is. Maybe they should be merged?

Comment: yeah, that is a good idea. The output is same.

Comment: I've posted an answer, which maybe should have been a question, see [here](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/naming-convention-for-tags-with-camelcase-or-pre-fix#answer-269)

Comment: @Greenonline In relation to my post in your Meta question, this would be a great example of Post-Processing since you're altering the physical dimensions of the material. It's similar to removing clamping stock when machining a part out of a mill or lathe.

Comment: @tbm0115 -  Nice one. Thanks, done.