# What is the difference between post-production and post-processing?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

What is the difference between [post-production](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production) and [post-processing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-processing), or are they synonyms? Should they be merged?<sup>1</sup>

[post-production](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production) has no description whatsoever.

After looking at [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work), We can make [post-processing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-processing) the master and [post-production](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production) the slave **synonym**. This would seem to be a logical relationship given the number of questions tagged respectively. This relationship can be easily removed, if deemed to be incorrect.

If, after some time, everyone is happy with this arrangement, then the two will be **merged**.

Does that sound like a plan and does anyone have any objections..?

---

<sup>1</sup> This question was moved from my answer to [Naming convention for tags with CamelCase or Pre-Fix](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/naming-convention-for-tags-with-camelcase-or-pre-fix#answer-269)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are **NOT** the same in a manufacturing, which 3D printing is primarily considered a part of.

Post-Processing typically refers to additional steps that must/can be done to produce the nominally desired part. These steps can include deburr, grind, and other additive/subtractive processing on the physical part.

Post-Production typically refers to any steps that typically do not "produce" or alter the dimensions of the product. These steps can include final visual and dimensional inspection, packaging, and sometimes even shipment.

I would not recommend creating a synonym, but merely updating the definition of both terms.

Answer (score -2):

Post Processing vs. Post Production: **[These terms are absolute synonyms. At the same time they can be interchangeable.](http://fixthephoto.com/blog/retouch-tips/editing-retouching-post-processing-post-production-difference.html)**

---

In digital video, photography, television and film, post-production refers to the tasks that must be completed or executed after the filming or shooting ends. This includes tasks such as the editing of raw footage to cut scenes, insert transition effects, working with voice and sound actors, and dubbing, to name a few of the many pre-production tasks. Post-production is the third and final step in film creation. It follows the pre-production and production phases.

Source: [Post-Production](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/post_production.html)